# why didn't I get exact same file size through node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple uploading code by node.js.

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url == '/upload') {
        var a = fs.createWriteStream('a.jpg', { defaultEncoding: 'binary'})
        req.on('data', function(chunk){
            a.write(chunk)
        })
        .on('end', function()){
            a.end()
            res.end('okay')
        })
    }
    else {
        fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(res);      
        // just show <form> 
    }
})
server.listen(5000)
```

when I upload some image, I cannot get exact same file. 
Always files are broken.

When I try to do this using formidable, I can get a fine file.
So I studied formidable but I cannot understand how did it catch data and save.
I could find formidable use parser to calculate something about chunk from request but I did not get it all.

(It is definitely my brain issue :( ).

Anyway, what is the difference between my code and formidable?
What am I missing?

Is it a wrong way to just add all chunks from http request and save it by
fs.createWriteStream or fs.writeFile ?

What concepts am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `req` is a Readable stream. You can simply do:

```
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('a.jpg'))
```

for the upload part. This is copying all byte data from request stream to file.

This will work when you send raw file data as the request body:

```
curl --data-binary @"/home/user/Desktop/a.jpg"  http://localhost:8080/upload
```

Because this sends request body exactly as image binary data, that gets streamed to a file on server.

But, there is another request format called `multipart/form-data`. This is what web browsers use with `<form>` to upload files.

```
curl -form "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/a.jpg" http://localhost:8080/upload
```

Here the request body contains multiple "parts", one for each file attachment or form field, separated by special "boundary" characters:

```
--------------------------e3f25f5319cd6624
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="a.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

JPG IHDRH-ÑtEXtSoftwareAdobe.....raw file data

--------------------------e3f25f5319cd6624
```

Hence you will need much more complicated code to extract the file part data from it. NPM Modules like [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) and [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) do exactly that.

Comment: OMG you are another angel of node.js! (first angel showed me yesterday. I solved some stupid making new connection on every data event emit by him - that's why files are very small - contains last chunk.)

Comment: Today, I know that the reason why files on the server are little bit bigger than original files. I cannot imagine that form attributes effects on request raw data. Thank you so much!